# 403 CSRF verification failed on Safari Private browser

Tags: python, django

can't figure it out why CSRF verification failed on safari private browser. Other rest of the browser all seems fine. Also have tested on safari browser but its working there but not on safari private browser.

I have used CSRF on form
<//form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}

and its redirecting to [image]